# Proving that the existence of a section implies the direct sum.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, modules, exact-sequence, module-isomorphism

Here is the question I want to prove so far:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. For $R-$modules $L,M,N$ show that the following conditions are equivalent.(all functions are $R-$ module homomorphisms.)

a- $M \cong_{R} L \oplus N.$

c- There exists a right-split short exact sequence $0 \rightarrow{L} \rightarrow{M} \rightarrow{N} \rightarrow{0.}$

**My trial is as follows:**

$a \implies c.$

Also, using the fact that the direct sum of a finite number of modules coincides with their direct product we will prove the required.

Assume that $M \cong_{R} L \oplus N.$ We want to show that there exists a right-split short exact sequence $$0 \rightarrow{L} \rightarrow{M} \rightarrow{N} \rightarrow{0.}$$ i.e., $\exists$ a section $s: N \rightarrow{M}$ s.t.$$p \circ s = id_N \quad (2)$$ Where $p: M \rightarrow N $ and it is onto. So we need to find the functions $s,p$ that satisfies $(2)$ above.

So, since $M \cong_R L \oplus N,$ we can say that we have $0 \rightarrow L \rightarrow L \oplus N  \rightarrow N \rightarrow 0,$ with $i:  L \rightarrow L \oplus N$ the embedding $i(l) = (l,0_N)$ and  $p:  L \oplus N \rightarrow N$ the projection $p(l,n) = n.$

Also, if we define $s: N \rightarrow L \oplus N  $ with $s(n) = (0_L,n)$ then we have $(p\circ s)(n) = p ((0_L,n)) = n $ as required.

Now, we want to verify that $s$ is an $R-$module homomorphism:

Let $n,n_1, n_2 \in N$ and $r\in R,$ then we have the following:

1- $s((n_{1} + n_{2})) = (0_L, n_{1} + n_{2})) = (0_L, n_{1}) + (0_L, n_{2}) = s(h_{1})s(h_{2}).$

Where the second equality is by definition of multiplication in the direct product.

2- $s(rn) = (0_L, rn) = r(0_L, n) = rs(n).$

And hence $s$ is an $R-$module homomorphism as required.

$c \implies a$

I do not know exactly how to define the isomorphism in that case, I am just guessing that it should be $\varphi :=(i,s): L \oplus N \rightarrow M$ for the following ses:

$$0 \longrightarrow L \stackrel{i}{\longrightarrow} M \stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow} N \longrightarrow 0$$

Where $i$ is injective and $p$ is surjective. **Is my isomorphism function $\varphi$ defined correctly?**

If so, I know that $\varphi $ is an $R-$module homo. (I can easily prove that), **but how can I show that it is injective and bijective?**

Could anyone help me in answering those questions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the $R$-module homomorphism $\varphi : L \oplus N \to M$ by $\varphi(l,n) = i(l) + s(n)$. Note that if $\varphi(l,n)=0$, then
$$\begin{align} 0 &= p(\varphi(l,n)) \\ &= p(i(l))+p(s(n)) \\ &= p(s(n)) = n \end{align}$$
($p \circ i = 0$ by exactness) and then $0=\varphi(l,n)=i(l)$ implies $l=0$ (since $i$ is injective). Hence $$\varphi(l,n)=0 \implies (l,n)=(0,0)$$ which means that $\varphi$ is injective. Can you now figure out how to prove the surjectivity of $\varphi$?

Comment: The proof of surjectivity is not very clear to me.

Comment: oh sorry I guess it is very trivial by that definition.

Comment: Is that correct?

Comment: why exactness means $p \circ i = 0$ could you clarify please?

Comment: @hard It is not too trivial. I'll write it and let you fill in the details: If $m \in M$, then $m - s(p(m)) \in \ker p = \operatorname{im} i$, and so there exists $l \in L$ with $i(l) = m - s(p(m))$, that is, $m = \varphi(l,p(m))$. P.S. $p \circ i=0$ because $\operatorname{im} i \subseteq \ker p$.

Comment: Ok thank you! I will try to fill the details and I will let you know if I am still stuck.

Comment: why we are sure that $m - s(p(m)) \in \operatorname{ker} p$?

Comment: Just apply $p$ to $m-s(p(m))$ and use the fact that $p \circ s = \operatorname{id}_N$.